# PlotLegends Below and Inside of a frame

Tags: plotting, legending

I whis to make that my labels are inside of the frame, as is shown in the following figure:
[image: whatIwish]

How can I do it? The best that I did is with the following code:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 28.27]}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Below, Center}]]
```

[image: WhatIobtain]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the symbolic position `{Center, Bottom}` but it gives a column layout for the legends:

```
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 28.27}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Center, Bottom}]]
```

[image]

which is easily modified with a simple replacement:

```
 % /. "Column" -> "Row"
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 28.27}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {{.5, 0}, {.5, -.5}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Use the approach by @kglr  `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 28.27}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend["Expressions", LegendLayout -> "Row"], {Center, 
    Bottom}]]`